# Can't get proper regex for this simple html

Tags: regex

```
<tr bgcolor='#C0C0C0'>
   <td>ID</td><td>personName</td>
   <td>homePhone<br>officePhone</td>
   <td>city</td>
   <td>street</td>
</tr>
```

ok, so this is a piece of HTML I get as a webresponse, and I need to parse it with grups to extract the ID, personName, city, homePhone, officePhone and street.

Can anyone give me a REGEX pattern for this? I've been trying for hours and I can't see where I'm wrong. Anyway is there any nice tool to create regex expressions, couse running the application over and over again is a pain. Thanks.

Comment: First off, RegEx is a poor choice as an HTML parser. You should use an HTML parser for your platform and language. Secondly What language/platform _are_ you using? RegEx dialects can be quite different.

Comment: Read here for detailed explanation regarding your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: http://www.regexbuddy.com/ is my tool of choice. It still won't save you from going insane if you parse HTML with regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming .NET ...)

This should do it:

```
(?s:<tr.*?>(?:.*?<td.*?>(?<content>.*?)</td>)*)
```

That extracts these values:

- `ID`
- `personName`
- `homePhone<br>officePhone`
- `city`
- `street`

It will return one match, with one group, with multiple captures.

For example, this code will write each value to the console.

```
var input = "<tr bgcolor='#C0C0C0'><td>ID</td>\n<td>personName</td>\n<td>homePhone\n<br>officePhone</td>\n<td>city</td>\n<td>street</td></tr>";
var pattern = "(?s:<tr.*?>(?:.*?<td.*?>(?<content>.*?)</td>)*)";

var match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);

foreach (var capture in match.Groups["content"].Captures)
    Console.WriteLine(capture.Value);
```

It will work with any number of cells. It ignores text, new lines and whitespace between cells. It ignores any attributes on the row or cell.

I use this tool for working with regular expressions: http://www.radsoftware.com.au/regexdesigner/

Comment: Thank you. This works great! But could you please explain what .*? does, and the meaning of s: and why doesn't .*? match the > immediately after? Can't find this anywhere.

Comment: (?s: expression  ) is an options modifier that puts it in 'single line mode'. In this mode, the "." character matches all characters *including* new lines.

The "*?" means a lazy match. That is, it captures as few characters as it needs to. So, something like ".*?>" will match any character until it hits an ">".